# Android Studio Emulator in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

When I run the emulator it gives me a black screen and it does not open after that and it does not show me any error in order to understand the problem and I can not close it except by restarting the computer.
My computer core i7 and 8 Ram. My cmd don't show any error

I can't find any solution to this problem ..

Comment: Remove it from avd manager in Android studio, and then create a new emulator.

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work